# Google Drive SDK - How to get the folder that a file is in?

Tags: java, google-drive-api

I am currently trying to get the folder(s) that a Google Drive file is in using the Google Drive Java API. I understand I have to use ParentReference, but no "getName()" or "getTitle()" method is provided, and there is also no way to find out if a "File" (I am talking about the one in Google's API!) object is a folder.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Your question is quite unclear. Can you post some code?

Comment: Show us something you've tried. your question is confusing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ParentReference is a ResourceId (file id). Once you have this ID, you can retrieve it's Title by calling

```
com.google.api.services.drive.Drive mGOOSvc;
...
mGOOSvc.files().get([parent ResourceId]).setFields("items(mimeType,title)").execute();
```

The best way to test it and figure out what fields to specify is at the bottom of [this page](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get) - section called ***Try It!***

The second question's answer (folder vs. file) is found in the 'mimeType' field of a GooDrive object .

```
"application/vnd.google-apps.folder".equalsIgnoreCase(mimeType);
```

If you have time to dig deeper, you may refer to this [demo](https://github.com/seanpjanson/RESTDemo/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/spjanson/restdemo/MainActivity.java) (createTree(), testTree()) that deals with issue of parents / children.

Good Luck

Comment: ... and don't be surprised to see multiple parents per object.